# Redirect desktop users away from mobile webapps with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

I'm trying to find a way to keep users on desktop website even if they type the url where the mobile website resides. for example. If someone types www.sitio.com/webapp, the user should remain on the desktop version. I have this code that works perfectly if the subdomain is done the other way around e.g. webapp.website.com.

```
RewriteEngine On
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} subdoamin [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|ipad|#operamobile|palmos|webos) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http:// %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

But I want this to work when users type www.domain.com/webapp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this new rule in `/appmovil/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /appmovil/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|ipad|#operamobile|palmos|webos) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=302]
```

Since I don't know URL of your desktop site I used a placeholder `/desktop-site`. You can change this to whatever you want.

Comment: Hi Anubhava, Thank you for replying to my question... I just added the domain in /desktop-site and it did not work, should I write the domain using http:// ? and where should I specify the subfolder name, in this case it is appmovil. So everyone who types http://www.domain.com/appmovil on a desktop computer remains in the desktop version http://www.domain.com. Thank you.

Comment: In the first line of the updated code, I see something like doamin right before www\.)?, is that supposed to be written like that or did you mean "domain" there... I tried the updated code and uploaded the .htacess and when I go to http://www.claudiaalvarado.com.mx/appmovil, it still remains on the webapp... What am I doing wrong? :-(

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by ` it still remains on the webapp`. Is `/webapp/` not `/appmovil/`?

Comment: Sorry... when I said webapp I referred to the appmovil folder where the source files of appmovil reside... It is appmovil the name of the subdirectory..

Comment: Thank you. I tried the updated code in the .htaccess inside of appmovil folder and still not working...

Comment: What URL are you entering in your browser? Q1. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? Q2. Is this the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code then please post it in question? Q3. What is location of above .htaccess?

Comment: R to Q1: I have another .htaccess in the root folder to redirect mobile users to mobile version from any mobile device. R to Q2: Yes, this is the only code in .htaccess above, I don't have any more code there. R to Q3: The location of above .htaccess is right inside a folder called appmovil where I am hosting the mobile version of the website. Thank you for your support and follow up.

Comment: I tried the updated code for /appmovil/.htaccess and it's not redirecting to desktop version.

Comment: What exactly is a `desktop version`? Above code will redirect to root URI if `%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}` is not in the given list.

Comment: when I say desktop version I mean http://www.domain.com. (Regular PC Website) Mobile version is http://www.domain.com/appmovil. If a user types http://www.domain.com/appmovil in any PC, they should not be allowed to view the mobile optimized website but the regular PC website.

Comment: Perfect!!!!!!! With this last code update it worked beautifully. Thank you Anubhava.